# Implementing WS-Security Using JBoss EAP 6.3 - Dfiferences between 6.3 and 7?

Tags: cxf, ws-security, jboss-eap-6, jbossws, jboss-eap-7

Recently I worked out a SOAP Web Service/WS-Security solution using JBoss EAP 7 and its JBossWS version (with CXF). This reference was very helpful:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBWS/WS-Security

The solution is based on a WSDL file that contains a WS-SecurityPolicy.

Now I've been asked to implement a solution based on the same WSDL file, but using JBoss EAP 6.3.

JBoss EAP 7 is the only version of JBoss EAP that I've worked with thus far. I would like to avoid re-inventing the wheel, so to speak, so I'm looking for a hopefully minimal set of configuration changes from the EAP 7 solution.

Does anyone have recommendations for doing this? I've struggled even to find documentation or tutorials, in part because I'm unclear about which version of WildFly, JBossWS, and JBossWS-CXF is included in a JBoss EAP 6.3 installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find out which component have been integrated into every JBoss EAP version, open the following URL:
https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673

You can check also [The WS-Security introduction page on the CXF website](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html)

Comment: Thanks, @panagiotis-chavariotis. Based on that link, the JBoss 7 EAP uses JBoss WS-CXF 5.1.3.SP1 and Apache CXF 3.1.4, and JBoss 6.3 EAP uses JBoss WS-CXF 4.3.0.Final and Apache CXF 2.7.11-redhat-3. Time to do some more reading!